# "ich bin das doppelte Lottchen"

Tags: meaning-in-context

The newsreader on Hessenschau today said at the very end of the [20 November 19:30–20:00 broadcast](https://www.hessenschau.de/tv-sendung/index.html), when she was announcing the rest of the programme at around 19:59:

> Presenter A: Und wir sehen uns um 22:15 wieder.
>
> Presenter B: Nach der Tagesschau gibts aber erst mal MEX.   Ich bin heute Abend wieder das doppelte Lottchen im HR.  Ich hoffe doch sehr Sie bleiben dran.  Schönen Abend.

I know [Das doppelte Lottchen](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Das_doppelte_Lottchen) as a children's book by Erich Kästner, in which twin kids for fun take each others position.

I don't know any metaphorical meaning.  What does the newsreader mean here?

Comment: I appreciate the video link, but could you tell us at what time the utterance occurs? I checked the end and it wasn't there.

Comment: @DavidVogt Looks like todays broadcast isn't online yet.  It's still in the [livestream](https://www.hr-fernsehen.de/livestream/index.html), at the time of writing at -35:00 but that will of course change :-/  Anyway, I added the full context and clarified the link to the livestream.

Comment: I would assume she is speaking about the situation that she appears in two different broadcasts simultanously - one prerecorded and one live. And on HR it is the tv station she is currently broadcasting that's why she says "ich hoffe Sie bleiben dran". It is not necessarily live on HR.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> > Und **wir sehen uns um 22:15 wieder**. Nach dem Tagesschau gibts aber erst mal MEX. Ich bin heute Abend wieder das doppelte Lottchen im HR.

She probably meant the repetition of her appearing later in the programme.

It's quite unlikely that she's got a twin to appear.

Comment: Is that a normal use of this phrase or is she saying something non-standard?

Comment: @gerrit More or less a joke probably, not standard.

Comment: @gerrit - But it's not the first time I heard it.